# XPath using string functions in the middle of the path

Tags: xpath, web-deployment, webdeploy

I'm trying to use Web Deploy 3.0 to make changes to my web.config before deployment. Let's say I have the following xml:

```
<node>
    <subnode>
        <connectInfo httpURL="http://LookImAUrl.com" />
    </subnode>
<node>
```

And I'd like to match just the "http" in "http://..." so that I can potentially replace it with https.

I looked into XPath string functions and understand them -- I just don't know how to put them in the middle of an expression, for example:

```
"//node/subnode/connectInfo/@httpURL/substring-before(../@httpURL,':')"
```

That's basically what I want to do, but it doesn't look right.

Comment: Your expression is fine in XPath 2.0 but not in XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  "//node/subnode/connectInfo/@httpURL/substring-before(../@httpURL,':')"
> ```
>
> That's basically what I want to do, but it doesn't look right.

But it is right and will match the http.

(Btw, you could write it shorter without ..

```
    //node/subnode/connectInfo/@httpURL/substring-before(.,':')
```

)

However, it will return the string "http" not some kind of pointer pointing to the value of @httpUrl, which is not possible, since there are no partial nodes within the value.

(In XPath 2,) you can return the attribute and a new value, and then perhaps change it in the calling language

```
    //node/subnode/connectInfo/@httpURL/(., concat("https:", substring-after(.,':')))
```

Comment: It's giving me an `invalid token` error in the XPath expression when I try to load the xml.

Comment: It is possible that it does not work with XPath 1.0.  I tested it with XPath 2.0 and there it is fine

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath 1.0, if you want to return the initial part of the URL use:

```
substring-before(//node/subnode/connectInfo/@httpURL,':')
```

Note though that this will return the value of ONLY the first `connectInfo` element.

If you want to get the `connectInfo` nodes that use HTTP:

```
//node/subnode/connectInfo[starts-with(@httpURL,'http:')]
```

If you wan to get all `httpURL` that use HTTP:

```
//node/subnode/connectInfo/@httpURL[starts-with(.,'http:')]
```